# Stacking daily data dataframe to get hourly output

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe which looks as:

```
df.ix[1:3]

          Val   endDay        startDay                             
1        2.20   1996-04-01    1996-03-31
2        5.15   1997-04-05    1997-04-01
```

The `startDay` however starts at hour `9 am` and continues until `8 am` on end day.

I am looking for the following output:

```
startDay     Hour   Val
1996-03-31   9     2.20 
1996-03-31   10    2.20 
                     ........
1996-03-31   24    2.20 
1996-04-01   1     2.20 
                     ........
1996-04-01   7     2.20 
1996-04-01   8     2.20
1997-04-01   9     5.15 
1997-04-01   10    5.15 
                     ........
1997-04-01   24    5.15 
1997-04-05   1     5.15 
                     ........
1997-04-05   7     5.15 
1997-04-05   8     5.15
```

I just used `.....` to represent the continuation of hours 11 through 23 and 2 though 6. I am not sure how to do this stacking pythonically.

Comment: did you try with merge ?

Comment: I am not sure how I can use merge because Hour column needs to be defined, not sure which option in merge will include that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just doing with [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) after create list of datetime

```
df['day']=[pd.date_range(x+' 09:00:00',y+' 08:00:00',freq='H') for x , y in zip(df.startDay,df.endDay)]
yourdf=unnesting(df,['day']).drop_duplicates('day')
yourdf
Out[909]: 
                  day   Val      endDay    startDay
1 1996-03-31 09:00:00  2.20  1996-04-01  1996-03-31
1 1996-03-31 10:00:00  2.20  1996-04-01  1996-03-31
1 1996-03-31 11:00:00  2.20  1996-04-01  1996-03-31
1 1996-03-31 12:00:00  2.20  1996-04-01  1996-03-31
...
```

Notice here I did not split the two columns with `date` and `hour` , that can be done with `yourdf.day.dt.hour; yourdf.dt.date`

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Comment: Didn't know the function unnesting .. thanks @Wen-Ben

Comment: @Zanam aah, that is one of function write by me no worry right now you know it :-)